# Why is this quicksort routine not working?

Tags: c, quicksort

I'm trying to use this to sort randomly generated numbers, so I print the random numbers, apply the quicksort and then print the sorted list, but it just gives me the numbers in the same order again.

```
  void quicksort(double x[], int first, int last)
  {

    int i=first;
    int j=last;
    if((j-i)<2)
    {return;}
    else
    {
        double pivot;
        pivot=x[(i+j)/2];
        if(i<j)
        {
            if(x[i]<pivot)
            { ++i; printf("%f\n", i); }

            else if(x[j]>pivot)
            { --j; }

            else if(x[i]>=pivot && x[j]<=pivot)
            {
                swap( x[i], x[j] );
                ++i;
                --j;
            }
        }
        quicksort(x, first, i);
        quicksort(x, i+1, last);
    }       
  }
```

Comment: Well, for one, that isn't quicksort. In fact its *no sort*. Check whatever this was copied from and you'll find `if(i<j)` should be `while (i<j)`. While fixing that, also fix your debug-output, which should be using `%d` for an `int`, not `%f`

Answer (score 1):

You're not showing `swap()`.

If that's a function, there's *no way* it can succeed since it only gets the values of `x[i]` and `x[i]`, not any addresses.

If it's a macro, it might work, but of course it's hard to tell without seeing it.

Comment: Sorry about that, here's my swap routine:


void swap( double a, double b)

{

 double temp;
 temp=a;
 a=b;
 b=temp;

}

Comment: @user2976296 That's your problem, right there. Just as I said, `swap()` cannot be a function based on how you're using it. There's no way for `swap()` to change `x[]` in the caller's context.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues with your implementation. The one that's causing your current problem is most likely the `swap` function, which if you tested it, I'm guessing probably wouldn't do any swapping. I suggest you replace it with something like this:

```
void
swap(double a[], int i, in j)
{
    double t = a[i];
    a[i] = a[j]; a[j] = t;
}
```

But then after that, there will be other issues in your implementation, because you are not partitioning the list properly.

Here's a reference implementation (I'm taking the pivot to be the first element in the range, which is non-optimal, but not less optimal than picking the middle element).

```
void
qsort(double a[], int lo, int hi)
{
   int i = lo, j = hi - 1;
   int pivot = a[i++];

   if(i+1 > j) return;

   while(i<j)
   {
       while(i < hi && a[i] < pivot) i++;
       while(j > lo && a[j] > pivot) j--;
       if(i<j) swap(a, i, j);
   }

   swap(a, lo, j);
   qsort(a, lo, j);
   qsort(a, j+1, hi);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, how would I partiton the list properly?

Comment: reference implementation incoming

Comment: @user2976296 by coding quicksort properly? There are *hundreds* of questions on this site alone concerning quicksort, most have functional examples either in the question or in the posted answers.